# How to hit "right-control" in VirtualBox on a remote Linux system over RDP via CoRD?

Tags: virtualbox

I'm connecting using CoRD to a remote Linux system running xrdp.  On that Linux system, I'm running VirtualBox.  To escape from Virtualbox, I need to hit a "right control" key.  Trouble is... I don't know how.

Anyone have experience with this kind of arrangement?  Suggestions?

Comment: how is this Apple related?

Comment: CoRD is a MacOS Application.  Microsoft Terminal Services Client on Windows sends the ctrl without a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reprogram the VirtualBox Host Key.  It seems to think my right-command key is a left alt, but the end result is the same, it works now.  [image: Virutalbox Host Key]

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to indicate there is an app called "Karabiner" that might be able to help you: https://superuser.com/questions/48362/emulating-the-right-ctrl-key-on-macbook-pro-keyboard-lacking-an-actual-right-ctr